# Using Laravel, What is the best way of handling a pivot table with up to four foreign keys

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I'm currently on a Many to Many relation where a table has up to four  foreign keys

`user_id` | `education_id` | `course_id` | `created_by`

where

`user_id` and `added_by` references `id` on `users` table.

`education_id` references `id` on `education` table.

`course_id` references `id` on courses table.

For an `api`, I would like to know the best way to handle this for performance. So far I'm able to add data but the challenge is retrieving data from related tables.

Below are the models.

```
//User Class
public function education(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Education::class, 'education_user', 'user_id', 'education_id')
        ->withPivot('created_by', 'course_id', 'institution', 'obtained')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }

//Education Class
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
}

public function courses(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Course::class, 'course_id');
}


//Course Class
public function education(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Education::class, )->withTimestamps();
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, )->withTimestamps();
}
```

From my controller, I have

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    return EducationUserResource::collection($user->education()->with(['courses'])->get());
}
```

Which returns the below data

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "data": {
                "education_id": 4,
                "name": "BSc",
                "last_updated": "7 hours ago",
                "course_id": 106,
                "course": '',//How can I get the name of the course where id on courses == 106 here
                "pivot": {
                    "user_id": 26,
                    "education_id": 4,
                    "created_by": 9,
                    "creator" : '', //How can I get the name of the user who created this resource here
                    "course_id": 106,
                    "institution": "Rivers State University",
                    "obtained": 2017,
                    "created_at": "2019-11-14 08:18:05",
                    "updated_at": "2019-11-14 08:18:05"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my Resource

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => [
                'education_id' => $this->id,
                'name' => $this->name,
                'last_updated'=> $this->whenPivotLoaded('education_user', function () {
                    return $this->pivot->updated_at->diffForHumans();
                    }),
                'course_id' => $this->whenPivotLoaded('education_user', function () {
                    return $this->pivot->course_id;
                    }),
                'course' => $this->whenLoaded('courses'),
                'pivot'=> $this->whenLoaded('pivot')

            ]
        ];
    }
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: `So far I'm able to add data but the challenge is retrieving data from related tables.` could you explain this a little more?

Comment: I'm able to attach record to the relation. I want to be able to see the course from `courses` table and the person who created the record from `users` table

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the table as a pivot table but as a full entity table. You should never have a "pivot table" with more than 2 relations, that's no longer a pivot table.

By creating a separate model for this table, you will make the querying much easier, with no need for complicated relations loading.

In your other models, you can use relations such as [`hasManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) to make sure you don't need to manually load this new model.

Comment: Thanks... I will start implementing this asap... I'll give a feedback

Comment: Thanks for your answer, "You should never use a pivot with more than two relations". It helped me.

Comment: Glad I could help, consider marking this as the answer so other users might find this as well.